# Natural measure on space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $C(I)$ to be the space of continuous functions on the interval $I=[0,1]$, we equip $C(I)$ with the norm $||f||=\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|$. Is there is a "natural" Borel probability measure on $C(I)$ such that we have the following statement:

Almost every continous function $f\in C(I)$ is not differentiable.

Comment: Two proposals: (i) The Borel $\sigma$-algebra associated to the compact--open topology. (ii) The minimal $\sigma$-algebra such that the evaluation maps $ev_x \colon C(I) \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable. I haven't tried to see how feasible they are but perhaps it's worth investigating them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wiener measure should give you this, but it is unfortunately a priori cumbersome to define.
You first need Brownian motion. A stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a family of random variables. We say that $X_t$ is a brownian motion if

1. $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is continuous for every $\omega \in \Omega$
2. $B_0(\omega) = 0$ for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$
3. for all $0 = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_n$, the random variables $B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i}$ are idependent and Gaussian with expected value $0$ and variance $t_{i+1} - t_i$.

We then define the Wiener measure on $C([0,1])$ by
$$\mathcal{W}(M) = \mathbb{P}([t \mapsto X_t]\vert_{[0,1]} \in M) \qquad \forall M \in \mathcal{B}(C([0,1])).$$
What happens here intuitively is that the Brownian motion gives us a bunch of random paths, and we can measure the size of a set of paths by how likely it is that a given realization of the Brownian motion is in this set.
Since all paths generated by Brownian motion are nowhere differentiable, under this measure paths are indeed almost surely nowhere differentiable.